# Проверить покрывается ли весь период

Tags: php, алгоритм

Дано:

Цельный отрезок времени (например - со 2 января по 20 августа).

Множество более мелких отрезков с произвольными датами начала и завершения в этом промежутке.

Их нельзя последовательно отсортировать по дате начала или дате завершения, т.к. мелкие отрезки могут пересекаться.

Необходимо проверить - полностью ли покрывается цельный отрезок более мелкими.

Какой алгоритм будет оптимальным?

Comment: *Их нельзя последовательно отсортировать по дате начала или дате завершения, т.к. мелкие отрезки могут пересекаться.* Поверь - можно. По дате начала. А потом пробежаться по отсортированному массиву и посмотреть, нет ли записи, где начало больше конца предыдущего элемента.

Answer (score 0):

> Их нельзя последовательно отсортировать по дате начала или дате завершения, т.к. мелкие отрезки могут пересекаться.

Можно упростить задачу сведением к непересекающимся отрезкам.

Алгоритм:

- Сортируем мелкие отрезки по дате начала.
- Бежим по отсортированному массиву. Если текущий отрезок пересекается с предыдущим или касается его, то сливаем его с предыдущим.
- Получаем массив непересекающихся отрезков, отсортированных по дате начала.
- Проверяем, есть ли среди них отрезок, полностью покрывающий период.

Для выполнения нужно научиться сливать два мелких отрезка в один.

Алгоритм можно улучшать:

- вместо слияния отслеживать максимальную дату завершения по отрезкам;
- отбрасывать отрезки, явно не попадающие в период;
- определять наличие промежутков уже при первом проходе.

Answer (score 0):

Сортируем сегменты по возрастанию левой границы (которая "от"). Заранее как-то определяем диапазон поиска (я просто зашил 1 и 9 в переменных from/to, у вас может быть иначе).

Стартуем с нижней границы диапазона и храним в переменной find ту часть диапазона, которую хотим проверить на покрытие сегментом (двигаясь при этом слева направо по оси времени).

Если встретили сегмент, который начинается дальше чем проверяемый участок - явно встретили дырку.

Если встретили сегмент, который заканчивается проверяемым участком (или лежит дальше за ним в будущем) - смело смещаем проверяемый участок до этой границы - до неё всё покрыто проверкой в этой итерации.

```
$segmentList = [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 4],
    [3, 6],
    [4, 5],
    [4, 5],
    [7, 8],
    [9, 9], // если поменять на [10, 10], будет дырка!
];

$from = 1;
$to = 9;

$find = $from;

usort($segmentList, fn($a, $b) => $a[0] <=> $a[1]);
foreach ($segmentList as $segment) {
    if ($segment[0] > $find) {
        throw new Exception("Найдена дырка диапазона");
    }
    if ($segment[1] >= $find) {
        $find = $segment[1] + 1;
    }
}

echo "Всё норм!";
```